# Can I add my own if statement to node.tpl to test if field groups are null?

Tags: theming, entities

I have a content type with 4 different field-groups utilizing the [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module. I want to test to see if those groups are empty and render them and some additional HTML if they are NOT empty, and not render them, and additional HTML, if all the fields in the group are empty.

I'm not sure of the syntax to test if field groups contents are NULL, any pointers there?

So far this still isn't working for me. I have a field group that I know is empty `group_factory_images`

When trying to use the code from the answer:

```
<?php if(!isset($node->group_factory_images))
print 'Yep, Empty';
?>
```

It just prints the "Yep, Empty" string.

Comment: At least you can  install Devel module and in node.tpl use dpm($content); to see the structure of content. You can always change $content with what ever is accessible for that template. I should take a look to say more concrete things

Comment: Hi, Erik. If you are using the [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module (or other) please indicate this in your post.

Comment: I am using [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group), edited the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example:

1. I created content type
2. In display settings for `Full content` display created group `group_mygroup`

If group elements are empty then group wil not be displaying. In this case you should check it:

```
//if node's group_mygroup does not exist
//in our case it means that all elements in group are empty
if(!isset($node->group_mygroup))
        print 'Group elements are empty';
print render($content);
```

As you can read in node template help part - block of comments:

```
 * Other variables:
 * - $node: Full node object. Contains data that may not be safe.
```

Now, what you can do to understand solution more clearly:

1. Install [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel)

> Helper functions for Drupal developers and inquisitive admins. This
>   module can print a summary of all database queries for each page
>   request at the bottom of each page. The summary includes how many
>   times each query was executed on a page (shouldn't run same query
>   multiple times), and how long each query took (short is good - use
>   cache for complex queries).

2. Somwhere in your template's code use
   `dpm($node);`
3. Create content of your type and see how it is displaying. You should see same picture
   [image: 1]
4. Click on header of appeared block and you can see structure of `node` object
   [image: 2]

If you want to check if some field doesnt exist - use same construction:

```
if(!isset($node->field_name))
print 'Field is empty';
```

Comment: +1 for [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module

Comment: Can I do the same to print something based off of the value of one specific field in the group?

Comment: Please, provide example

Comment: So far this isn't working for me. I have a group of images "group_factory_images" that I know are empty, yet this isn't doing anything in the node:

`if(!isset($node->group_factory_images))
  print 'Yep, Empty'`

Comment: I installed Devel, interesting thing is that it only shows fields, not groups. With that being true is seems to me we can't actually do any testing on the group to see if it's has contents.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this evaluated as expected. `if(empty($content['group_limited_edition']))`

Comment: Sure, group array was listed in my case. Mb you looked at Devel's dpm output for 'display without group field'?

Comment: I was just looking at the output it gave me. I'm still having a hard time hiding and printing items that are inside tab groups. Are there some parameters I need to give to dpm to have it show everything?

Comment: If it helps, the group is inside a horizontal tab, I know the field group is not empty, but I only want to show it if another field is not empty. I can handle the if statement, I just can't for the life of me get the group to hide at all, even with a direct hide statement. I also can't get it to show with `<?php print render($content['group_limited_features']); ?>` which I'm guessing means I'm just not calling the right thing, but that is the machine name of the group, but it's inside an htab.